# Vector Spaces of a set of continuous funtions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

I am having trouble with a homework problem.  This is the problem:

Determine whether the set, together with the indicated operations, is a vector space.  If it is not, then identify at least one of the ten vector space axioms that fails.
$\mathcal C\,[-1,1]$, the set of all continuous functions defined on the interval $[-1,1]$, with the standard operations.

Comment: Do you know what the axioms for a vector space is?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I have the list of all ten of them.

Comment: The problem, Asif, is that I'm how to work this.  I must prove that it either is, or isn't a vector space.  Essentially, if I cannot "break" an axiom with it.

Comment: What is the first axiom?

Comment: The closure under addition: u+v is in V

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are two continuous functions on $[0,1]$, then is $f+g$ also continuous?

Comment: Let V be a set on which two operations (vector addition and scalar multiplication) are defined.  If the listed axioms are satisfied for every u, v, and w in V and every scalar c and d, then V is called a vector space.

Comment: Yes. They are continuous.

Comment: Why does my education on Vector Spaces involve only eight axioms?

Comment: @GeoffPointer Mine had only one: A vector space is an abelian group on which a field acts. (And no, this could not be "simplified" to module over a field because he had not covered modules then)

Comment: @ElizabethVemmer Following the path suggested by Brian: What is the second axiom?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's cheating. An abelian group and a field each presuppose several axioms.

Comment: I think the point is, Elizabeth, that you go through the axioms one by one until you either prove they all work or find one that doesn't. You've made a good start --- keep going!

Comment: You should be clear what $+$ and $\cdot$ mean on the space $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Commutative property: u+v=v+u

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous function from a connected space to a totally disconnected space must be constant, and thus any continuous function from $[-1,1]$ to a totally disconnected vector space $V$ (such as a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_p$ or a number field, with the topology induced by the base field) is constant. So the set of continuous functions from $[-1,1]$ to $V$ is in bijection with $V$ via the map $f\mapsto f(0)$ and thus can be endowed with its vector space structure (induced by the bijection), so $\mathcal{C}[-1,1]$ is a vector space.

I'll leave the more difficult case of connected fields for another user.